# Feature Scaling required or not

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am working with [sample data set](https://github.com/brenden17/sklearnlab/blob/master/facebook/snsdata.csv) to learn clustering. This data set contains number of occurrences for the keywords.

Since all are number of occurrences for the different keywords, will it be OK not to scale the values and use them as it is?

I read couple of articles on internet where its emphasized that scaling is important as it will adjust the relativity of the frequency. Since most of frequencies are 0 (95%+), z score scaling will change the shape of distribution, which I am feeling could be problem as I am changing the nature of data.

I am thinking of not changing values at all to avoid this. Will that affect the quality of results I get from the clustering?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is the year a feature or a label in this data? What could you predict with this data?

Comment: Since you have a data set, why don't you just try it both ways and see what works better?

Comment: @IVlad, I did try both ways, but I am not very familiar with how to really measure the effectiveness of the clustering. Just by eyeballing it , without scaling approach is looking better. But then I was thinking weather I am doing something unconventional or completely unacceptable.

Comment: @ Valentine, I am not sure if dataset is there for prediction, i am trying to cluster it as per interests. So may be a new profile comes one can say its more like these people etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it was already noted, the answer heavily depends on an algorithm being used.

If you're using distance-based algorithms with (usually default) Euclidean distance (for example, k-Means or k-NN), it'll rely more on features with bigger range just because a "typical difference" of values of that feature is bigger.

Non-distance based models can be affected, too. Though one might think that linear models do not get into this category since scaling (and translating, if needed) is a linear transformation, so if it makes results better, then the model should learn it, right? Turns out, the answer is no. The reason is that no one uses vanilla linear models, they're always used with with some sort of a regularization which penalizes too big weights. This can prevent your linear model from learning scaling from data.

There are models that are independent of the feature scale. For example, tree-based algorithms (decision trees and random forests) are not affected. A node of a tree partitions your data into 2 sets by comparing a feature (which splits dataset best) to a threshold value. There's no regularization for the threshold (because one should keep height of the tree small), so it's not affected by different scales.

That being said, it's usually advised to standardize (subtract mean and divide by standard deviation) your data.

Comment: how about tree-based regression, loss function are still based on distance (for instance mse)?

Comment: @ADJ, Tree-based regression is no different. Regression computes MSE / MAE between the prediction and the ground truth, but it does not require you to use any metric in the feature space.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I meant scaling/transformation for target/response variable, not on features

Comment: This question is about feature scaling. But even for continuous targets in tree-based regression there's no need to normalize data. This is because the tree only interacts with the target by taking its average over some subsets of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it depends on the classification algorithm. I'm only familiar with SVM. Please see [Ch. 2.2 for the explanation of scaling](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf)

The type of feature (count of words) doesn't matter. The feature ranges should be more or less similar. If the count of e.g. "dignity" is 10 and the count of "have" is 100000000 in your texts, then (at least on SVM) the results of such features would be less accurate as when you scaled both counts to similar range.

The cases, where no scaling is needed are those, where the data is scaled implicitly e.g. features are pixel-values in an image. The data is scaled already to the range 0-255.

Comment: In fact there is no such simple rule as "no scaling is needed if". You will never know such thing. There are numerous methods of scaling, many of which might help despite such basic data characteristic. min-max scaling which you refer to is a trivial approach, but not neceserly the best one

Comment: @lejlot Interesting to know. Could you provide a good link to other methods or something in general on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

*Distance based algorithm need scaling
*There is no need of scaling in tree based algorithms

But it is good to scale your data and train model ,if possible compare the model accuracy and other evaluations before scaling and after scaling and use the best possibility
These is as per my knowledge